# Telegram that sends messages in response to inline keyboard on behalf of user?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

My bot shows an inline keyboard in a group that the users have to click in order to send a preset message to the group.

The bot presents the preset text and pass it as `callback_data`:

```
bot.telegram.sendPhoto(process.env.TELEGRAM_GROUP_ID, {
  source: filepath
}, {
  reply_markup: {
    inline_keyboard: [[
      { text: text, callback_data: text }
    ]]
  }
})
```

[image]

Then when the user click the button the bot send a reply that shows the reply keyboard showing the preset text:

```
ctx.replyWithHTML("instructions", {
  reply_markup: {
    resize_keyboard: true,
    one_time_keyboard: true,
    selective: true,
    keyboard: [
      [text]
    ]
  }
});
```

[image]

Is there a way to show the reply keyboard without having to send a separate message, or maybe to have the preset text to apear in the text box ready to be send by the user instead of on a button in the reply keyboard?

Comment: You may use a callback query. It does not send a message instead it calls your api directly using your provided callback url: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery

Answer (score 3):

`Question :`

**May I insert a text into text box that user can send it to the bot?**

`Answer` :

**NO**

`Question :`

**Is there a way to show the reply keyboard without having to send a separate message?**

`Answer :`

**Yes , You can update your message with a/many inline keyboard (inline button)**

`Question :`

**Where can I read bout Inline-keyboard?**

`Answer :`

**Here is [document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery)**

`Question :`

**Any source example?**

`Answer:`

**Yes , Here is some [example](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/306)**